# Dell Vostro 2520 WiFi not working after Ubuntu 14.04 update

Tags: wireless, drivers, kernel, dell, broadcom

I tried the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Wireless worked for sometime but after reboot WiFi stopped again.

Can someone please help?

Software center in additional drivers says:

```
Broadcom Corporation: Wireless 1704802.11n + BT 4.0 This device is using an alternative driver Using Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel-source (proprietary)
```

What is the alternative driver? And how to find it?

Also, do help resolve this issue fast.

Comment: what is the output of `sudo lspci`?

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: Output of sudo lspci
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
07:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)

Comment: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/8071047/

Comment: The following worked for me on 12.04 LTS

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69199/wireless-not-working-after-update-network-unclaimed